# Bootstrap 3 "btn-group" non-responsive behavior on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a bootstrap 3 way to handle small screen sizes for "btn-group"?

Button group is placed in `<td>` and wrapped in `<div class="btn-group">`:

[image: btn-group]

Looks okay, until you re-size it to <768px. Then you have:

[image]

How to make them persistent? I tried to add class `btn-group-justified`. But it gives as a result full width buttons and looks even worse on re-size to small screen size.

P.S> I have an idea, how to implement it adding full set of custom classes. My question is about bootstrap3 way. May be I missed something.

Comment: Found a solution yet? I can't understand why Bootstrap doesn't handle this natively...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I want to offer you a version with icons from [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.io/). 
With a minimum screen resolution text hide leaving only icons.

Sorry for my english.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> View</span></button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i><span class="hidden-xs"> Delete</span></button>
</div>
```

**UPDATE by [Vishal Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920291/vishal-kumar): add GLYPHICONS preview**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeen/w33GD/4/

Comment: And in case you don't want to use font-awesome, you can use the bootstrap icons also. There, instead of using fa fa-eye, you will be using glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open

Answer (score 26):

You can create two button groups with the same buttons and make one of them `btn-group-vertical`. Then after applying the `hidden-xs` and `visible-xs` to them you can hide and show vertical group on appropriate screen size.

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-xs">
    <button class="btn btn-default">View</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group-vertical visible-xs">
    <button class="btn btn-default">View</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this requries repeating the markup of the buttons but it should not be an issue if you use any templating tool (define the markup once and include it twice).

**Wide screen:**

[image: Wide screen buttons]

**Narrow screen:**

[image: Narrow screen buttons]

See [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w33GD/19/).

Comment: This works and I use something similar in production, but we have to face the fact: This is wrong in so many ways. You increase HTML size, cause duplicated content (displayed or not should not matter on the low level), confuse crawlers and you have to customize css classes when you add too many buttons over time, overall it will look horrible with more buttons.

Comment: Solid way to do it but I would recommend adding a custom class to the btn-group. Then copy the css from btn-group-vertical as well as the standard btn-group and use css media queries to switch between the two rather than having duplicate html.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative to @fracz's answer you can try that won't duplicate HTML content. Just copied the css from btn-vertical-group and btn-group and used a media query.

All you have to do is add btn-toolbar-responsive to the toolbar div's classes.

It's in scss for simplicity although you can convert it online easily. Here is the JS Bin:
[demo](http://jsbin.com/suboba/1/edit?html,css,output)

SCSS:

```
.btn-toolbar.btn-toolbar-responsive{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  .btn-group{
    float: none;
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px){
    .btn + .btn,
    .btn + .btn-group,
    .btn-group + .btn,
    .btn-group + .btn-group {
      margin-top: -1px;
      margin-left: 0;
    }


    .btn-group{
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin: 0;
      .btn {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 100%;

      }
      .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
      .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      }
      .btn:last-child:not(:first-child) {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
      }

    }
    .btn-group:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
      .btn {
        border-radius: 0;
      }
    }

    .btn-group:first-child:not(:last-child) {
      .btn:last-child, .dropdown-toggle {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      }
    }

    .btn-group:last-child:not(:first-child) {
      .btn:first-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this worked in a test page I made:

```
<div class='btn-group'>
    <button class='btn btn-default col-xs-6'>View</button>
    <button class='btn btn-default col-xs-6'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Forcing each button to be 50% using col-xs-6 kept it from wrapping in my own test page modeled after your example.  However, if you have a wider table than the example and you squish down to 320px, the text will overflow the buttons and it looks even worse than your bad example.

You may already know this and it may not be practical for your situation, so I apologize if I'm just presenting unhelpful examples.  However, if your table is much wider than what you posted as an example, I would suggest making your rows using the BS grid instead of a table.  What this allows you to do is make a single row become two rows when the page shrinks, e.g.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6'>Some additional details</div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3'>Date</div>
    <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3'>
        <div class='btn-group'>
            <button class='btn btn-default col-xs-6'>View</button>
            <button class='btn btn-default col-xs-6'>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then, just find a way to alternate colors, add borders, or whatever you need to show the separation between the multiple row rows.

In the BootPly that I just made, as I said, the buttons start to overlap at very small sizes, but they don't wrap when inside a `<td>` in my browser tests:

http://www.bootply.com/117330

Comment: Thanks for the research. But in that case it doesn't work either :( 
[http://clip2net.com/s/6U4Ijy]
[http://clip2net.com/s/6U4HF2]

Comment: @IliaShakitko I added a bootply link for you.

Comment: Well ... until you have too many buttons that take too much width

Answer (score 2):

try to set **min-width** on `<td>`

```
<td style="min-width: 90px">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-circle" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </button>
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-circle" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
        </button>
        <button class=" btn btn-default btn-circle" type="button">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="secondNav" class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button class='btn btn-default'>View</button>
    <button class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

You can accomplish this with some simple jQuery

```
<script>
$(window).resize(function() {
    justifyBtnGroup('secondNav');
});

function justifyBtnGroup(id) {
    var btnGroup = $('#' + id);
    if($(window).width() > 768) {
        btnGroup.addClass('btn-group').removeClass('btn-group-vertical');
    } else {
        btnGroup.removeClass('btn-group').addClass('btn-group-vertical');
    }
}
justifyBtnGroup('secondNav'); // will run when page loads
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This help for me. It doesn't make the buttons vertical, but it doesn't compress them either

```
<div class="btn-group flex-wrap" data-toggle="buttons">
```

Answer (score -2):

No, If you open page in small screen, bootstrap **wrap** you buttons.

Comment: That is not a correct answer. At least, because adding `btn-block` to the div make them persistent. But it is already block of buttons (separated), not connected to each other.

Answer (score -8):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">...</div>
<div class="btn-group">...</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">...</div>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">...</div>
```

you can add the class (btn-group-xs,btn-group-sm) in the media < 720px

hope it will help you ;)

Comment: Damn, I can't minus answers. Have you read the documentation? Those classes are introduced to have different sizes for button group. Have you tried it before suggesting? From documentation: `Instead of applying button sizing classes to every button in a group, just add .btn-group-* to the .btn-group.`

Comment: then you can use only font size... your buttons size connected whit your font size

Comment: I don't have anything to do with button size. The question title is: Bootstrap 3 "btn-group" non-responsive behavior on small screens. Try to build simple `btn-group` with 3 buttons. And re-size the window to a very small, you will see what happens with the buttons. But please, after that, do not suggest me to add `white-space:nowrap;` to a css, because I asked for advice, how to win this w/o bringing new styles. Only bt3.

Comment: you can do something like this <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg btn-group-sm btn-group-xs">...</div>

Comment: Have you actually tried what you said in your last comment? that'll just make buttons have the btn-group-xs style. What they should implement is something like btn-group-lg-xs that makes buttons have "lg" size when the screen is "xs"

Comment: @VostanAzatyan you are absolutely not competent in that offer, Ilia Shakitko correct recommend you first read the documentation